# Dialog is not displaying textview & imageview

Tags: android, textview, android-dialog

I am new to android world and am working on dialog and in that I am trying to create a text view, button and imageview, but it is neither showing me error nor textview or imageview. It is showing a button. Here is the image:

[image: dialouge].

But i am want to display my dialogue as follows

[image: need as this]

My xml file is as follows ....

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".AddFriendsCustomActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/submit_dialog"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="37dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/add_Friend"
        android:src="@drawable/add" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit_dialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="64dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/add"
        android:text="@string/submit" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/writename"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/add"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"

        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/add"
        android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am calling it in java file as follows

```
dialog = new Dialog(context);
                     LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                        View view = li.inflate(R.layout.activity_add_friends_dialog, null, false);
                        dialog.setContentView(view);
                        dialog.setCancelable(true);
                    //dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_friends_dialog);
                    //dialog.setTitle("Add Friends");
                    add= (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.add);
                    friends1 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.writename);
                    submit_dialog = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.submit_dialog);
                    add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {

                            try {
                                friendsCount++;
                                            Log.d("addFriendsActivity", "ashish comes here ");
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                        }
                    });

                    submit_dialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {

                            Intent i = new Intent(AddFriendsActivity.this, DetailsFriendsActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);

                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();
```

After some google I understand that the issues might be in r.java or you have imported android .r  but i have not done any thing in this ..
Thanks in advance.... :)

Comment: Can you post the desired design which you want to achieve with this code?

Comment: Try to set the background of your `ImageView` besides setting `src`. like `android:background="@drawable/add"`

Comment: @GrIsHu I am want to display my dialogue as above..

Comment: hey just posted a full similar working example have a look

Comment: @all why -1  can any one tell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error in your java code. Its perfect you have just change your xml. Use this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#FFFFFF"
  tools:context=".AddFriendsCustomActivity" >

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/writename"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/writename"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/writename"
    android:contentDescription="Add Friend"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit_dialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/writename"
    android:layout_below="@+id/add"
    android:layout_marginRight="46dp"
    android:text="Submit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Nothing...You have just set in center so thats problem. Use this xml file and run it.

Comment: 01-13 15:26:46.914: W/System.err(343): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText
01-13 15:26:46.914: W/System.err(343):  at com.ace.budget.AddFriendsActivity$1.onClick(AddFriendsActivity.java:50)

Comment: in your code you have to change this line friends1 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.writename); to friends1 = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.writename); and also this EditText friends1;

Answer (score 2):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/writename"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit_dialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 1):

For your xml I think it should look like this:

```
    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/my_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/add_btn" />

    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/add_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/add_btn"
        android:background="@null" />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/submit_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/my_edit_text"
        android:text="Submit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Be aware that there can be some typo mistakes, because I didn't compile that code, and you should change your real variables. And create your `AlertDialog` like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
View mView = mInflater.inflater(R.layout.my_layout, null, false);
EditText mEdit = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text);
ImageButton mImageBtn = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.add_btn);
Button mSubmit = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);
mBuilder.setView(mView);
AlertDialog mAlert = mBuilder.create();
mAlert.show();
```

Using `AlertDialog.Builder` instead of `Dialog` is lot more easier for your situation (at least in my opinion). And you can add your `Submit Button` to your `AlertDialog` as default `positive` button.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code i think

```
add= (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.add);
friends1 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.writename);
```

as

```
add= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.add);
friends1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.writename);
```

That should work.

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay yeah first i have read the question wrong so, have edited the answer.

Comment: replace your `LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);` with this one and check `LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(AddFriendsActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_friends_dialog);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

        add= (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.add);
        EditText friends1 = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.writename);
        submit_dialog = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.submit_dialog);
        add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            //@Override
            @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            public void onClick(View v) {
                            friendsCount++;
                            //TextView  textview  = new TextView(context);
                            //textview.setId(friendsCount);
                            //final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            //params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, friendsCount--);
                            //textview.setLayoutParams(params);
                            //textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            //relativelayout.addView(textview ,params);
                            Log.d("addFriendsActivity", "ashish comes here ");
            }
        });

        submit_dialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        Intent i = new Intent(AddFriendsActivity.this, DetailsFriendsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                    }
                });

        dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view is covered.
May be you can try to set your parent layout to Linearlayout, not RelativeLayout.

Comment: what should I do can you help me on this ?

Comment: Please change your xml. Use LinearLayout to replace RelativeLayout and add android:orientation="vertical".